# $S$ as a subspace over $\mathbb R$ vs. as a subspace over $\mathbb C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $S \subset \mathbb C^n$ be an over-$\mathbb R$-defined subspace of $\mathbb C^n$ and $B=\{b_1, \ldots, b_m \}$ an $\mathbb R$-basis of $S_{\mathbb R}$. Show that $B$ is also a $\mathbb C$-basis of $S$. That would imply that $\dim_{\mathbb R}(S_{\mathbb R})=\dim_{\mathbb C}(S)$

I must be missing something but isn't $S_{\mathbb R}=S_{\mathbb C}$? I thought it's the same set and we simply add the index to indicate that $S$ should be thought of as a vector space over such-and-such field?

If so, why is the statement true? Say, $S=\mathbb C$ and $B=\{1, i\}$ is a basis of $S$ over $\mathbb R$ but not over $\mathbb C$.

How does one show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, $S_{\mathbb{R}} = S \cap \mathbb{R}^n$.  The claim is not asserting that $S$ has the same dimension as a real and a complex vector space.